# Access Database in Servlet

Tags: jsp, ms-access, servlets

jsp file which contains username & password which is processed at LoginServlet...this servlet does the validation in Access db. but i m getting error

if username & password matches with the access db then the page redirect to flat_status.jsp

can any1 help me out..

```
    package Validate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        super.init(config);
            try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Initialize connector string");
        }
        }
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
                Connection conn;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
            try 
            {
                conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:FBS");
                st=conn.createStatement();
                rs=st.executeQuery("select UserName,Password from user_login where UserName='"+userName+"' and Password='"+password+"'");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    session.setAttribute("USerName",userName);
                    RequestDispatcher dispatch=request.getRequestDispatcher("/flat_status.jsp");
                    dispatch.forward(request, response);
                }
            st.close();
            rs.close();
            conn.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                  pw.println(ex);  
            }
        }

        }
```

Here is Exception i m getting in Browser window

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Which line is line 58 of LoginServlet? My guess is that it's the line `out.println(ex.getMessage());`, since you write to out, which is initialized to null.

Comment: @^^...what is solution on that ? when i remove PrintWriter and used System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); it shows me empty servlet page after click on submit button

Comment: It shows you an empty page because you have an exception. If you don't want an empty page, then print an error message to the response writer.

Comment: You can't call a method on a null reference. That's what causing the NullPointerException. To write something to the response, you write `response.getWriter().println(...)`.

Comment: null pointer exception is the result of referencing an object that is null.  This is the magical information that points to the line where the null object is being referenced: `Validate.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:58)`.  The file containing the bad reference is LoginServlet.java (I suspect that you wrote this file) and the line number is 58.

Comment: @Sagar: why can't you be bothered to form real sentences with full words and to communicate as a professional instead of as a kid with a mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use PreparedStatement and Password is reserved keyword in Ms-Access.

```
  boolean userFound=false;

  conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:FBS");
  String sql="select [UserName],[Password] from user_login 
                            where [UserName]=? and [Password]=?";
  PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  st.setString1(1,userName);
  st.setString1(2,password);
  rs=st.executeQuery();

  if(rs.next())
   {
    userFound=true;
   }
  st.close();
  conn.close();

 if(userFound)
  {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things jump out at me.

The first is that in the init, you should only have to call

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

without an additional "newInstance()".  In fact, if you're using a JRE that supports JDBC 4.0, you shouldn't even need the "Class.forName(...)" call

The second is that you should only need the double slashes to escape
forward slashes in the path.  Try changing the connection string to:

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:FBS={Microsoft Access Driver(*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Dumbre\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Flat Booking System\\Flat_System.accdb;");
```

Additionally, you might try switching to a DSN, just for testing.  Create a system DSN
and your connection string should be:

```
jdbc:odbc:TheNameForTheNewDSNThatYouJustCreated
```

Well, obviously that last part has to be the actual name.

Comment: will Sure give it a try and let u know..!!